# Deploy .ear file in to geronimo

Tags: web-applications, tomcat

I need to deploy an .ear application into "geronimo" apache (java) aplication server.

I need to replace an OC4J server, and i think i would replace it with geronimo.

When i try to deploy a working .ear file from OC4J into geronimo, it gives some errors.

Can someone help, can it be done?
Is Geronimo a good replacement for OC4J (oracle)?

Thanks

Flip

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done.

Geronimo is a very good replacement for all J2EE Web containers, including the oracle offerings. I would recommend Geronimo before JBoss, simply for the portability you loose wehn using JBoss (not referring to portability across OSes but the portability between different Web containers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now does anyone knows why the .ear file doesn't work?